# How to Add an object to a list of objects without a reference in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a created a custom type in C# called `InfInt`. Each `InfInt` object has its own list of ints declared as follows:

```
public List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();
```

Then, elsewhere in the program, I have a loop where a temporary `InfInt` object is needed. At the end of the loop, when temporary `InfInt` has been filled with information, I want to add this object to a list of `InfInt` objects which is declared like this: `var ListOfLists = new List<InfInt>();`. The following code adds the temporary `InfInt` object to `ListOfLists` list of `InfInt` objects:

```
ListOfLists.Add(Temp);
```

Then, right when a new iteration should start, I obviously need to clear the data in the temporary `InfInt` object. I use the following code for this:

```
Temp.Numbers.Clear();
```

Now comes the problem. When I clear the `Temp`'s data, it is cleared in `ListOfLists` too... How should I fix this?

Comment: Don't call `.Clear` but create a new `Temp` object

Comment: instead of clearing, why don't you make a new object? `Temp = new InfInt();`

Comment: OMG, it is so simple. Thank you so much! I am new, did not know that.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a deep copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects. I don't see the need in this case though.

Comment: You start by showing a `List<int>`, but then you never refer to that again.  I'm guessing that `InfInt` is a class.  I'm also assuming that `Temp` is a variable that refers to an `InfInt`.  When you assign a class instance something to a variable, it no longer refers to what it used to refer, instead it refers to what you just assigned.  So, if you say `var temp = Get()'; MyList.Add(temp);` it adds what temp refered to to the list.  If you run that again, and the `Get` function returns a different object, temp refers to that object and that object is added to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clearing your Temp using

`Temp.Numbers.Clear();`

You should make a new Temp object

`Temp = new InfInt();`

Answer (score 1):

`InfInt` is a reference type which means that temporary `InfInt` variable is pointing to an object. When you add it to the list and then clear it, the content of this instance is cleared.

In your loop, create a new instance of `InfInt` instead of re-using that temporary `InfInt`.

Here is [a MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types) that describes the difference between Reference Type and Value Type.